# Sum of random variables dependent on an ODE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let us assume we divide a piece of membrane into $n$ parts. Every part contributes with a specific electric potential, which is represented by $X_i\ $ $(i=1,\dots,n)$ random variables. So with probability $p_i$ the part $X_i$ is sending an impulse (mostly this impulse should be in the range of $[0,1]$).

- All $X_i$ are independent - maybe we can assume a $N(0,1)$ distribution.
- The $X_i$ are dependent on the total membrane voltage $V(t)$.

> I want to show that the standard deviation of the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$$ grows proportional to $\sqrt{n}$.

I can show that the standard deviation grows proportional to $\sqrt{n}$, when neglecting the dependency on $V(t)$.

But I don't know how to deal with the dependency on a function. Maybe it would be a good idea to model the dependency regarding $dV/dt$?

Shall I look at $\sum_{i=1}^{n}V(X_i)$?

I don't know how to handle this issue.

Comment: You say "All $X_i$ are independent" and "The $X_i$ are dependent on the total membrane voltage $V(t)$".  I am not sure these two statements are consistent.  How might the $X_i$ be affected by $V(t)$?

Comment: Similar setup to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132341/random-variables-in-dependence-of-a-function and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124914/ionic-current-fluctuations

Comment: (1) You say $X_i$ depends on $V(t)$... _how_ do they depend on $V(t)$? Is it just that they have a certain mean/variance which is a function of $t$? (2) If you want $X_i\in [0,1]$, then you cannot have $X_i\sim N(0,1)$. Normal variables can be negative, or be arbitrarily large.

Comment: de dependence should be the following - the higher V(t) , the higher the impulse of part $n$. So there should be a correlation. What would be , if the mean of the X_i depends on V(t) ? kind regards and thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that when the voltage is $V$, the standard deviation of $X_i$ is $\sigma(V)$. Then the standard deviation is
$$
\operatorname{St. Dev}(\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\sigma(V(t))\sqrt{n}.
$$
Without more knowledge of the dependence of $\sigma$ on $V$, this is all you can say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why should the standard deviation be $\sigma(V)$? Ah you mean if the mean of the $X_i$ are dependent on V(t)?

Comment: Sorry of course the standard deviation of $X_i$ is influenced by $\sigma(V)$ - do you see any possibility to maybe simulate the dependence? Or to obtain more knowledge of the dependency ?

Comment: @Calculator123 That sounds like more of a physics question then a math one.

Comment: maybe you are right @mike Earnest - one thing additionally : what do you mean by $\sigma(V)$ ? whats the standard deviation of a deterministic function?

Comment: @Calculator123 For example, suppose that $X_i$ is equal to either $0$ or $1$ (either their is a pulse, or there isnt), where $P(X_i=1)=1-e^{-V}$. The higher the voltage, the higher the chance of a pulse. The standard deviation of $X_i$ can be [shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) to be $\sqrt{e^{-V}(1-e^{-V})}$, so this last expression would be $\sigma(V)$. $\sigma(V)$ is not the st. dev. of $V$. It is the standard deviation of $X_i$, but it depends on $V$, so we must write it as $\sigma(V)$.

Comment: Ah okay - you assume the $X_i$ having an exponential distribution. Would this also be possible using the ODE $dV/dt$ instead of V(t) ?